# Python - filter column C based on column A, but column D data is linked to C

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is a data set where I need to filter out data from column 'if' to then sort and match based on 'Desc'. But if/Status are linked and need to stay together. Column Desc/ONT is data that needs to stay tied together as well.

if/Status was a single column that I divided into two,(1627662401 up), is it possible to filter out the needed data from C before this stage?

'if' needs filtered to match 'Desc' but keep 'Status' data tied to 'if'

```
TestMerge.csv
Desc(A)      ONT(B)         if(C)       Status(D)
16292413441  ADTN210784db   25300071    down
16292423681  ADTN21078135   25300072    down
16292433921  ADTN210780ef   25300200    up
16292444161  ADTN2039e094   25300201    up
16292454401  ADTN201242db   1627653120  up
16292464641  ADTN2019306c   1627653185  up
```

This is what I used to create the data set.

```
import pandas as pd


df_1 = pd.read_csv('TEST_ifDescr.csv')

df_2 = pd.read_csv('WG_ifOperStatus.csv')

frames = [df_1, df_2]

df = pd.concat(frames, sort=False, axis=1)

df.to_csv('TestMerge.csv', index=False)`
```

Desired output would be:

```
16292413441  ADTN210784db   16292413441 down
16292423681  ADTN21078135   16292423681 down
16292433921  ADTN210780ef   16292433921 up
16292444161  ADTN2039e094   16292444161 up
16292454401  ADTN201242db   16292454401 up
```

To make this more clear, I need to remove any value in C that is not in A, but also remove/keep values in that relate to C.

For example I need all values in C like '500004' to be removed, but also remove 'testing' in D on the same row as C.

I'm open for any suggestions. Thank you to anyone who reads and responds!

Comment: How looks expected ouout from sample input data posted in question?

Comment: Don't use screenshots of data. Instead using code fencing to format it.

Comment: I think instead `concat` need `merge`.

Comment: @jezrael Desired output would be Column A and C match, but data in D column stays with C

Comment: yes, I am right, need merge. `df = df_1.merge(df_2, left_on='Desc', right_on='if')`

Comment: @Nick thanks for the pointer, I'll stay away from screen shots.

Comment: @jezrael I replaced df = pd.concat(frames, sort=False, axis=1) with your comment. However now the csv has many empty rows from the top for columns Desc/ONT(A/B). I added "axis=1" but received an error.

Also, one objective was to remove any value in column if(C) that wasn't in A. But I need to keep C and D rows aligned. 

Thank you for the engagement in this post!

Comment: It is inner join, how possible `However now the csv has many empty rows from the top for columns Desc/ONT(A/B)` ?